# iPhone crash log

Tags: iphone

do you explain the foollowing crash log......

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController createAddressBookCopy]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5908300'.
```

what does it mean?
my code is here....

```
-(NSString *)pathOfFile{
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //lastName.text=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"contacts.plist"];
}


-(IBAction)createAddressBookCopy{

UIActionSheet *actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Wanna create a copy of Addressbook?"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                            destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yeah!!!"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];



ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

NSMutableArray *masterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) {
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
    CFStringRef fName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFStringRef lName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", (NSString *)lName];

    CFRelease(fName);
    CFRelease(lName);
    [masterList addObject:contactFirstLast];
    //[contactFirstLast release];
}

//self.list = masterList;
[masterList writeToFile:[self pathOfFile] atomically:YES];

[masterList release]; 

}

//creating action sheet

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *) actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex!=[actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Copy creaeted."
                            message:@"New copy is contacts.plist"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"DONE" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil
                            ];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your method `createAddressBookCopy`. Can your post your code on how u call and define the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `IBAction` is connected properly. I think its not connected properly. Check if the declaration of the method in .h file is same.

Comment: are there any difference in connection between view based and tabbar based app?

Comment: How do u declare this method in .h file of your view controller and how do you connect them?

Comment: -(NSString *)pathOfFile;
-(IBAction)createAddressBookCopy;

Comment: Actually i am working with an tabbar base app...i am creating copy in second tab. so to connect action i opened nib file for second tab..and then add action to a button of this nib file to file's owner.

Comment: second tab has a different view controller right? And if this method is set up in first tab how can it be accessed in second tab?

Comment: yes second tab has different view controller..i named it as nib file for second tab.Do i have to do anything else.

Comment: Did u declare this method in first tab bar's view controller?

Comment: Make sure you connect the method to the view controller used in the second tabbar

Comment: thanks ...i have only one createAddressBookCopy method...do i have to indicate which file is the view controller for second tab although i have named it as nib file for second tab?...if i do. How can i do that?

Comment: Connect it to the nib file which has the method. In your case i guess second view controller

Answer (score 1):

You have sent the message `createAddressBookCopy` to a `UIViewController` object. The app crashed because `UIViewController` does not have a method of that name.

Comment: my code works in view based app...but when i am using tabbar it crushed...why?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have some code that tried to call the `createAddressBookCopy` method on a `UIViewController` instance.  According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), no such method exists, hence the crash.

Answer (score 1):

That means that some object in your program trying to send `createAddressBookCopy` message to `UIViewController`, but this `UIViewController` object doesn't implement such method

Answer (score 1):

UIViewController doesn't have a method called createAddressBookCopy. I suspect you have a UIViewController subclass which does have that method, but for some reason you're calling the super class. This sometimes happens if you're using interface builder and don't have your outlets hooked up correctly.